# I am getting poor cluster results when using Dynamic Time Warping as a similarity measure in k-means for time series data. How can I improve?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, time-series, cluster-analysis

I want to cluster the Xi's.
Each row consists of the value of Xi's at a particular timestamp. Here's the dataset.:

```
X1  X2  X3  X4

100 100 100 100

91.56786232 96.62190102 98.08459941 96.54390935

92.90859973 97.64075269 103.1123983 98.13031161

.... .... .... ..... ..
```

Also, I know that the Xi's are correlated. Thus, I also tried to perform hierarchical clustering based on co-relation matrix. Any other approaches I could try?

Comment: What would be the clusters in this example?

Comment: side note: k-means is well defined only for euclidean distance, using it with arbitrary similarity is a terrible idea.